# How do I find the bounds of integration for a triple integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

[image: ds]

How do I find the bounds of integration for this?

I assume I need to find the standard equation for this so I put it like so:

$$\frac{x}{7}+\frac{y}{9}+\frac{z}{2}=1$$

and so I solve for $z$. Then I solve for $y$ by making $z=0$ And then repeat for X.

And so here are my bounds:

$$\int _0^7\int _0^{9-\frac{9x}{7}}\int _0^{-\frac{2x}{7}-\frac{2y}{9}}(z)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Which equals $\frac{63}{2}$ which isn't the correct answer.

How would I find my bounds of integration here?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you get that as the equation of the plane?  Isn't $(0,0,0)$ a point on the plane?

Comment: Look at the picture. The plane is parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, I was looking at a different plane.

Comment: could you convert to cylindrical/polar coordinates, as it is nearly the wedge of a sphere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outermost integral can be with respect to $x$, as the cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are all the same. Its bounds are $0$ to $a$.

The middle integral will be taken with respect to $y$ and be from $0$ to $b$. But the range of the innermost integral (in $z$) depends on whatever value of $y$ is "in effect" when the innermost integral is evaluated: we have a constant lower bound of $0$, but the upper bound linearly varies from $0$ at $y=0$ to $c$ at $y=b$. The function describing this is $yc/b$. Thus, our final triple integral is
$$\int_0^a\int_0^b\int_0^{yc/b}z\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: thanks! amazing stuff